# How to use dynamic variable name in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I need a dynamic variable in nodejs .

I use the allocine-api, and she return, a different object when I use it . For example :

```
        allocine.api(type, {code: code}, function(error, result) {
        if(error){
            console.log('Error : '+ error);
            return; 
        }
        socket.emit("allocine_"+type ,result);
    });
```

if type is "movie", result contain a movie object, but if type is "tvseries", result contain a tvseries object. So I need to take the variable "originalTitle" in "tvseries" or "movie" object, so I need to make this :

```
result.<type>.originalTitle
```

But, how to use the contain of "type" for this ?
I have try with the javascript method, and the use of "window['type']", but it's don't work in nodeJs .

Comment: What is result? Where is it defined?

Comment: I have make one update

Comment: Still hard to understand. There is no to level window object available in node. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I try to name a variable dynamic, I can have : 
result.movie.originalTitle or result.tvseries.originalTitle, the change is in the variable type, how to call the good variable ?

Comment: I don't understand what a dynamic variable is.

Comment: a dynamic variable name ( I forgot one word )
the same of : $$name; in PHP

Comment: result[type].originalTitle

Comment: result is not a array, it's juste one object containing object ( movie or tvseries )

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: @r043v and what I need read ?

Comment: "Properties of JavaScript objects can also be accessed or set using a bracket notation. Objects are sometimes called associative arrays, since each property is associated with a string value that can be used to access it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as javascript objects elements can be accessed as an associative array ( cf [mozilla js doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) )

using *myobject.myproperties* is strictly equal to use *myobject["myproperties"]*
so if a var hold the properties name to read *var myvar = "myproperties";* you could also use *myobject[myvar]*

so, concretely :

```
var o = {
    tvseries : {
        originalTitle : "hello world"
    }
}, type = "tvseries";

console.log( o[type].originalTitle );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cod26jq/)

also, if the result object get only one sub object, named by the type, you can get type name directly from it

```
var type = Object.keys( myobject )[0];
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cod26jq/1/)

or more simply :

```
var theTitle = myobject[ Object.keys( myobject )[0] ].originalTitle;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cod26jq/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = {};

results.a = {originalTitle: "One"};
var results2 = {b:{originalTitle: "Two"}};

console.log(results['a'].originalTitle); //now one
console.log(results2['b'].originalTitle); //now Two
```

With two ways of creating the object.

Try the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rmoskal/6rf0juq6/

Comment: yes but, I need to take one variable in one object, I have one object ( unamed ), and he contain one object tvseries or one object movie, How make a generality ?